Python - Two UDP clients listening on the same port
This has been asked many times in different ways and always has the same kind of answer, asking why would you want this, not answering the question.
My scenario is as follows:
Proprietary control and automation hardware which uses python for programming. One of the types of device we control requires strings over UDP on a specified port. I can have 1-20 of these devices I need to send commands to and receive responses from.
Obviously binding to the socket will only allow the first client to listen, throwing an error for any subsequent bind attempts. Using socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1) or socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEPORT, 1) allows the code to start without error, however only the first client that bound itself to the port actually receives the responses.
Is there a way without making a class of some sort, that has a single binding per port and handles the receiving and distributing of responses? Each of those devices are usually represented by a class with a udpclient class that manages the sockets itself so creating a singleton to dish out sockets would not be my preferred route.

An unicast packet is delivered only to a single socket. You cannot deliver the same packet to multiple sockets. You could only use raw sockets (SOCK_RAW not UDP) which just listen to arbitrary traffic and then filter out what they need. Each raw socket gets a copy.

"of some sort" is a key phrase that points out that you are lacking a system design. That is a problem we don't handle at Stack Overflow.

Klaus: There is plenty of system design. Other languages such as C# handle this trivially.
Steffen: I am aware how unicast works. I am not asking for packets to be delivered to multiple network sockets. I'm asking for multiple python socket class instances to get those packets received on the physical port.

The sockets API allows you to create pseudo-connections with UDP, so that packets from a remote address/port are always delivered to the same socket.
What you do is create a single socket to listen for new packets from any device with socket.recvfrom(). When it receives this packet, it creates a new socket and calls new_socket.connect() using the sender address and port from recvfrom(). You can hand this socket off to a new thread or process to handle all future messages from that client device.
This requires that the client device always uses the same source port for each message. I don't think you can connect just to an IP without a port.
An alternative is to just use one receiving process with a single socket. Use recvfrom() to get the remote address, and map the address to a class instance for that device.

When I do this, the main port is still the one receiving data, and the new_socket cannot new_socket.recvfrom(buffer_len)
Each new device is going to be connecting on the same port, with multiple devices running simultaneously. Will this not cause the same issue as manually instantiating them?

It should distinguish them by the remote address and port. Are you sure that the client is using the same source port for all the messages? That's the requirement I mentioned in the last line.

All the documentation I can find state if connect is used for a UDP socket, and an existing instance already exists using that port, it will be replaced.

There shouldn't be an existing instance using the same remote address and port.
